# No booting device after last ubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: boot

I had a dual boot with Ubuntu and windows 10. Yesterday night I just turned off from Ubuntu as always and today when I tried to turn on the PC I received a no boot device message from the PC. Luckily I can boot from my USB pen the 18.04 iso I have but I cannot install anything. I can mount and access the other partitions on the PC but still the installation doesn't go forward. I also tried to format one of the partition so now I have only windows installed.
Any suggestion? PC is hp-15r239nl

Comment: Is it possible that the hard drive has crashed?

Answer (score 0):

If your screen looks like this:

[image: No Bootable Device.jpg]

Follow these [instructions](https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/).